# I can't find the linux version for aarch64 to download

Tags: java, javafx

I can't find the aarch64 version of JavaFX for Linux.

I was looking at https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ and I can't find the aarch64 version for Linux.
I use a Raspberry Pi and without this version I cannot run my applications.

A few months ago I downloaded it but now it disappeared.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can fine early access versions under "unsupported platforms".

Comment: @JoséPereda  It's so strange because a few months ago I downloaded the aarch64 linux version from the website and now the team removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

If you select the small checkbox to "include older versions" and choose any relatively recent version **that is not an LTS version**, then the JavaFX download options for linux aarch64 for that version are available as "Unsupported Platform" downloads.

As an example, when I did this, the Linux aarch64 JavaFX SDK gluon download early access 22-ea+16 version could be downloaded from:

- https://download2.gluonhq.com/openjfx/22/openjfx-22-ea+16_linux-aarch64_bin-sdk.zip

And the 21 (non-LTS) release version was available from:

- https://download2.gluonhq.com/openjfx/21/openjfx-21_linux-aarch64_bin-sdk.zip

The above links may not be stable and I recommend you download via the Gluon download webpage:

- https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

[image: screenshot]

**Alternative**

BellSoft Liberica currently offers a "Full JDK" or "Full JRE" distribution that includes JavaFX for Linux arm64 (JDK 21):

- https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#jdk-21-lts

**FAQ**

> It's so strange because a few months ago I downloaded the aarch64 linux version from the website and now the team removed it.

The current stable JavaFX version displayed on the JavaFX download page is a 21.x branch which is an LTS (long-term support) release (this may change with time).

From my understanding, Gluon doesn't offer long-term support for the aarch64 linux versions, so it does not show up as an option when an LTS version is selected for download.  The same is true for older LTS versions like 17.

Previously, the current stable JavaFX version displayed on the JavaFX download page was, for example, 20, 19, or 18.  Those aren't LTS releases, so the aarch64 download shows up for those releases as a downloadable version under "Unsupported Platforms".  Perhaps, when JavaFX 22 is released, that will be the default version selected on the Gluon download page, and the "Unsupported Platforms" section there will reference the Linux aarch64 version.

**Related**

- [JavaFX 21 for Linux aarch64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78263233/1155209)