# JavaFX app running on windows but not in linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, intellij-idea, javafx

I creted an app using jaxafx and intellij, in windows works fine but when i execute the jar in linux with:

```
java --module-path javafx-sdk-21.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar  ./i-ViSta4bike2.jar
```

I get this error:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:263)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:275)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    ... 2 more
```

I tried everything i could find on the internet, i just want to run my app in both OS.

Comment: I have a similar project, where I have to run from IDEA on different OS. I have the following module path (javafx is a dependency is the project) for MacOS, but it's similar on Linux, just relative to the home folder:
`--module-path
/Users/my_user/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/17.0.2/javafx-base-17.0.2-mac-aarch64.jar:/Users/my_user/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-media/17.0.2/javafx-media-17.0.2-mac-aarch64.jar:/Users/my_user/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/17.0.2/javafx-graphics-17.0.2-mac-aarch64.jar`

Comment: Verify that you have the correct [version](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) for your platform and architecture; see also comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77445734/230513).

Comment: You could run `jlink` or jpackage on your target Linux system to create a runtime image or installer that you can use on that target Linux system.  For information on using jlink refer to the ["Runtime Images" section of the JavaFX getting started documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular).  Oracle have a [guide for jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A).  Or you can download relevant jmods from Gluon and include them with your app distribution on the module path.

Comment: Not all Linux versions are capable of running JavaFX apps out of the box.  For instance, I think archlinux won't as it uses [musl](https://musl.libc.org) rather than glibc.  Similarly, stripped-down server versions of Linux that don't include the xWindows client windowing system won't run JavaFX apps.  The graphics and CPU hardware of the system also needs to be compatible with your JavaFX version.  A standard full client distribution by a major vendor (e.g. Ubuntu or Fedora) should run JavaFX apps (of the same CPU architecture) without additional software installs.

Comment: Please add your Linux distro, the installed JDK and your Java compile version.