JavaFX 21 for Linux aarch64
If we look at the Maven repo (using JavaFX base as an example) for Long Term Support (LTS) JavaFX 21 version 21.0.1 we see a jar for linux-aarch64:
JavaFX 21.0.1 base module
If we now look at the later version 21.0.2 JavaFX jars are no longer provided for linux-aarch64:
JavaFX 21.0.2 base module
Why is it no longer supported? I thought Java / JavaFX 21 was LTS?

Thanks. There are differences between the SDK and Maven Repo, and interested in the Maven jars. You state "hence an LTS version is not offered and only non-LTS versions are offered", but if this is true then why was it offered for 21.0 and 21.0.1 and then stopped from 21.0.2 onwards? This is my point - once you add Linux Aarch64 to the LTS 21, then that is a commitment. It's a feature of an LTS version.

I've noticed that not every minor release of an LTS version gets to maven; for example versions 17.0.(3-5}.

It certainly appears irrational. No SDK for 21.0.2, and yet an SDK for 22 on Gluon's website.

At the community support level, I saw a steady stream of version 17 updates; I simply waited for the next minor release. Is that practical in your case?
